# Compound Modifier in "Information Storage and Retrieval System" - No Hyphen

Tags: hyphenation

The term "information storage and retrieval system" seems well established, but "information storage" is a compound modifier preceding the nouns yet has no hyphen in almost every instance I can see written online. Is this correct? I know that using hyphens in compound modifiers is often considered an issue of style, but typically I see most style guides recommend that compound modifiers preceding the noun (*well-established convention*) should be hyphenated, whilst ones after the noun need not necessarily be so (*the convention is well established*).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's a storage and retrieval system.  *Information* modifies both *storage* and *retrieval*, or, perhaps better, *storage system*  and *retrieval system*. You say "preceding the nouns" but there's only one noun--system--although the others are, I suppose, technically nouns used as modifiers.

If I had to hyphenate it, I'd write it "information storage-and-retrieval system";
I'm glad that was avoided.

Comment: Apologies, yes, my question wasn't worded that well. I'm now thinking of "information" acting as a modifier on "storage and retrieval system" and it makes sense not to hyphenate that purely because it wouldn't look good, if for no other reason. Thank you very much.